Does quanity of chicken tikka cut on skews need a certain amount of coal?
We do a lot of chicken tikka cut on skews and using Bar-Be-Quick lumpwood, which comes in bags of 10, each bags is 1.35 kg. When doing bbq, is there a propotion to how much bags I should use for x amount of kg of chicken.
